# How to communicate cloud spring-boot with files which are available on azure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, cloud

We have a built a spring boot application which invokes a command-line eclipse tool and generates few output files. Configurations for eclipse tool is added in the `application.properties` file. This is successfully achieved locally. Now, we have deployed the spring-boot application to azure cloud and able to access the REST apis. But stuck while invoking the eclipse command-line tool. How to upload the commandline tool into azure and access it through the cloud app?

Comment: Need more details. How do you invoke the eclipse command line tool from your Sping Boot app? What is the difference between the environment in Azure cloud and in your local machine? Is the eclipse command line tool part of your application as a dependency?

Comment: Eclipse application is invoked from the command prompt by passing the inputs, this eclipse application is present in a local drive. Eclipse command line tool isn't part of the dependency, it's a separate tool present in other location. It's like invoking any other windows application from the command prompt.

Comment: Well theres your answer in that case. Make sure your Azure machine would have this thing installed.

Comment: I am not sure how to make this eclipse application to be available in the cloud. How this application can be installed in cloud?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what the actual application is and what is the host running in the cloud. If I were you, I'd Dockerise my application and try to get this utility installed in docker via Docker scripts. Then you could just deploy your Docker container to the cloud and wouldn't have to burden your head between the differences in cloud and in your local environment.